# Blocking Domain* in apache

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, block, blacklist

I have been receiving massive bot attacks from ahrefs bot from several specific domains like "hydrogen084.a.ahrefs.com", "hydrogen172.a.ahrefs.com" etc which is eventually causing my server to hang and not allowing the site to come up. Is there any way I can prevent this domain hydrogen*.a.ahrefs.com to stop hitting my server (Apache). Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first idea is to block this bot and similar in your .htaccess

```
# Block abusive spiders
BrowserMatchNoCase "Baiduspider" bots
BrowserMatchNoCase "Yandex" bots
BrowserMatchNoCase "MegaIndex" bots
BrowserMatchNoCase "AhrefsBot" bots
BrowserMatchNoCase "HTTrack" bots

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bots
```

Then take a look at this article. https://perishablepress.com/eight-ways-to-blacklist-with-apaches-mod_rewrite/

Look at the section blacklist via the User Agent and the other sections for ideas.

Blacklisting via user-agent is a commonly seen strategy that yields questionable results. The concept of blacklisting user-agents revolves around the idea that every browser, bot, and spider that visits your server identifies itself with a specific user-agent character string. Thus, user-agents associated with malicious, unfriendly, or otherwise unwanted behavior may be identified and blacklisted in order to prevent against future access. This is a well-known blacklisting strategy that has resulted in some extensive and effective user-agent blacklists.

Of course, the downside to this method involves the fact that user-agent information is easily forged, making it difficult to know for certain the true identity of blacklisted clients. By simply changing their user-agent to an unknown identity, malicious bots may bypass every blacklist on the Internet. Many evil “scumbots” indeed do this very thing, which explains the incredibly vast number of blacklisted user-agents. Even so, there are certain limits to the extent to which certain user-agent strings may be changed. For example, GNU’s Wget and the cURL command-line tool are difficult to forge, and many other clients have hard-coded user-agent strings that are difficult to change.

On Apache servers, user-agents are easily identified and blacklisted via the HTTP_USER_AGENT variable. Here is an example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$                                                              [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*                            [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|nikto|miner|python).* [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(winhttp|libwww\-perl|curl|wget|harvest|scan|grab|extract).* [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @John Hanley. Looks like it worked for me. You rock !!!!.... I have also have Fail2Ban in my server which helps me to rate limit the incoming IP's.. So looks like I am safe now with these two in place... Thanks again!!!